# how to deploy a heavy size files using chef

Tags: knife, chef-infra

I have a file which is of 900 MB approx.
 I want to deploy the file to the target machine. I used the files resource in chef  (`cookbook_file`). But i am unable to upload the cookbook in to the server because of the size.

Is there any way to deploy the file on the target machine rather than downloading it from internet (using `remote_file`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, Chef server is no artifact server. It is a bad idea to upload large binaries to the chef server. Place them on some server in the intranet or maybe add an Apache HTTP server to the node running the chef server and upload the files there. And yes, then use the `remote_file` resource.

Comment: Additionally, cookbooks **are** limited in size.

Comment: Just for curiosity: What's the limit?

Comment: 50mb I think. Not sure

Comment: more than 100 mb. I tried copying a 110 mb file and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

We had similar issue. Since our requirement is that the huge file should be on chef server before deployment to client.
We had just used split command and used cat command to join on target node. It worked well ..